# Module that converts index to a value: syntax error near text "="; expecting ".", or "("

Tags: verilog

This module is supposed to convert the index value `iState` into the corresponding value in the array `sequence` and return it as `oV`. However, I get this error at `oV = sequence[iState];` when I run it:

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at assign32498071.v(70) near
> text "=";  expecting ".", or "("

```
module StateToCountSequence(iState, oV);
    //declare the input and output 
    input iState;
    output [3:0]oV;
  
    //declare any internal wire and reg types here.
    reg [3:0]sequence[14:0];
    
    initial begin
        sequence[0] = 4'd3;
        sequence[1] = 4'd2;
        sequence[2] = 4'd4;
        sequence[3] = 4'd9;
        sequence[4] = 4'd9;
        sequence[5] = 4'd0;
        sequence[6] = 4'd7;
        sequence[7] = 4'd1;
        sequence[8] = 4'd1;
        sequence[9] = 4'd5;
        sequence[10] = 4'd1;
        sequence[11] = 4'd7;
        sequence[12] = 4'd0;
        sequence[13] = 4'd8;
        sequence[14] = 4'd9;
    end

    oV = sequence[iState];
endmodule
```

Does anyone know what I should do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `assign` keyword for your continuous assignment to `oV`.  Change:

```
oV = sequence[iState];
```

to:

```
assign oV = sequence[iState];
```

That fixes the compile error.

---

It is strange that your index signal (`iState`) is a 1-bit signal, which means it can only take on the known values 0 and 1.  Thus, you can only access `sequence` [0] and [1].

---

Note that `sequence` is a SystemVerilog keyword, which means that it can not be used as a signal name if SV features are enabled with your tools.  I recommend changing the name to something else.